# Unable to pass parameters from HttpClient but able to from postman

Tags: firebase, ionic3, angular5, google-cloud-functions

I am having firebase http triggers.

```
export const handlePayment = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    console.log('In handle Payment');
    console.log('amount '+req.body.amount+' currency '+req.body.currency+' receipt '+req.body.receipt);
    console.log('amount '+req.amount+' currency '+req.currency+' receipt '+req.receipt);
    res.status(200).send();

});
```

I tried to invoke this from postman and worked.
[image]

```
info: User function triggered, starting execution
info: In handle Payment
info: amount 50000 currency INR receipt 1NZY3IOCQ1bp6dHjmLF6
amount undefined currency undefined receipt undefined
info: rzp response [object Object]
info: Execution took 363 ms, user function completed successfully
```

but when I am trying the same from angular 5 httpclient module, the cloud function got triggered but no parameters are going.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import {Http, Headers, RequestOptions,URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
import {HttpHeaders,HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-about',
  templateUrl: 'about.html'
})
export class AboutPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,private http:Http,private httpClient :HttpClient) {

  }

  callfunc(){

    //var headers = new Headers();
    //headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json' );

  let httpOptions = {
 headers: new HttpHeaders({
   'Content-Type':  'application/json'
 })
};

    //console.log('amount '+paymentInfo.amount+' receipt '+local_id);
   // let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    let postParams = {currency : 'INR',amount:'50000',receipt   :'454545454' };
    /*let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set('currency', 'INR');
    params.set('amount', '50000');
    params.set('receipt', '21212121212');*/
    let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    //return this.http.post
    console.log('calling handlepayment');
    return this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:5000/fizion-f4286/us-central1/handlePayment',JSON.stringify(postParams),httpOptions)
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log('success '+data['_body']);
        //return data['_body'];
      }, error => {
        console.log('err '+JSON.stringify(error));// Error getting the data
        //return error;
      });

  }

}
```

Below is the log for firebase http triggers.

```
info: User function triggered, starting execution
info: In handle Payment
amount undefined currency undefined receipt undefined
amount undefined currency undefined receipt undefined
Function crashed
info: Error: `amount` is mandatory
    at Object.create (I:\fizion-functions\functions\node_modules\razorpay\dist\resources\orders.js:72:15)
```

So what I am missing here? Please ignore the response in the working case, I just removed the corresponding code from firebase cloud function.

Comment: @DougStevenson could you also help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cracked it finally.

```
console.log('amount '+req.body.amount); // This will not work.

const data = req.body;
console.log('amount '+data.amount); // This works.
```

What is the difference and why? I don't know. It will be very helpful if someone explains.